# How to disable error message in REST API output

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Recently I have upgraded WordPress theme and plugins of my website to enable REST API. My site has more the 30 thousand custom post types currently with few meta information. When I try to access `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/book` It gives me a fatal error about allowed memory size which has full file name with the full path of my hosting server.

I want to disable the error message or replace the error message with something else so that file path does not display. How to do it?

FYI, I have used the following constant in the wp-config.php file to solve this issue but no luck.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

[image: Shows the error with file path in hosting server while request REST API]

Comment: Sorry, I use false value for WP_DEBUG constant in the wp-config.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution at [wpmudev](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/debugging-wordpress-how-to-use-wp_debug/) to hide the error message displaying in the REST API output:

After the line `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` add the line:

```
@ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: With this code you enable displaying errors. It should be:
`@ini_set('display_errors', 0);`